# centralizing horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hangout</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site">
            <!-- header -->
            <div id="header">
                <div id="menu" align="center">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html"        class="btnHome active">     <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html"    class="btnPort">            <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html"            class="btnVideos">          <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html"            class="btnNews">            <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html"            class="btnGallery">         <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html"            class=" btncontacts">       <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html"            class=" btnAbout">          <img src="images/btn/spacer.gif"    alt="" width="120" height="36"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
text-align : center;
}
html {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
background-color : #222222;
}
body {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
background: url('images/hdr-bg.gif') top left repeat-x;
}
#site {
width : 988px;
margin : 0 auto;
}
#header {
padding : 15px 0 15px 0;
width : 988px;
overflow : hidden;
position : relative;
}

#menu {
width : 988px;
height : 36px;
margin : 0;
padding : 0px 0 0 14px;
}
#menu ul {
overflow : hidden;
padding : 0 3px 0 0;
}
#menu li {
display : inline;
list-style-type : none;
}
#menu a {
display : block;
float : left;
}

.btnHome{background:url('images/btn/Home.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnPort{background:url('images/btn/Port.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnVideos{background:url('images/btn/Videos.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnNews{background:url('images/btn/News.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnContact{background:url('images/btn/mid.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnGallery{background:url('images/btn/Gallery.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btncontacts{background:url('images/btn/contacts.png') top left no-repeat;}
.btnAbout{background:url('images/btn/About.png') top left no-repeat;}
#menu a:hover, .active {
background-position : bottom left;
}
```

hi, i have 2 problems with the menu.first is centralizing the menu. i cant take out the float left coz then my menu wouldnt be horizontal. and the second thing is btn pics seems like they dont stick to each other in IE. 
and btw, the length of each btn***.png is 120px
would appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to do with `display: inline-block;`.

```
ul {text-align: center; font-size: 0;}
li {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; *zoom: 1; *display: block; font-size: 12px;}
```

Comment: yea the problem is even that doesnt work as well! and i dont wanna put space between them i want to make them stick to each other! =/